# Perl RegEx for matching char '*' in first position of the string

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to match the line starting with a char '*'. The file mac-address.txt is as follows:

```
Legend: * - primary entry
    age - seconds since last seen
    n/a - not available

vlan   mac address     type    learn     age              ports
------+----------------+--------+-----+----------+--------------------------
*   14  782b.cb87.b085   dynamic  Yes          0   Gi4/39
*  400  c0ea.e459.913d   dynamic  Yes          0   Gi6/21
*  400  0017.c59a.23aa   dynamic  Yes          0   Gi3/37
*  400  d4be.d96a.050f   dynamic  Yes          0   Gi1/12
```

I have got something like this working.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;
my $line;
open FH, '<', "mac-address.txt";
while ($line = <FH>)
{
    if ($line =~ m/^\S/){
    print ("$line");
    }
}
close FH;
```

But it works along with some unwanted lines as follows:

```
Legend: * - primary entry
------+----------------+--------+-----+----------+--------------------------
*   14  782b.cb87.b085   dynamic  Yes          0   Gi4/39
*  400  c0ea.e459.913d   dynamic  Yes          0   Gi6/21
*  400  0017.c59a.23aa   dynamic  Yes          0   Gi3/37
*  400  d4be.d96a.050f   dynamic  Yes          0   Gi1/12
```

Please can you help me with some appropriate way such that only the line containing the * is preserved and the others are eliminated. Please inform me if something is wrong. Thank you.

Comment: To downvoter. Any reason?

Comment: Actually this is a very well done question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to escape the `*` because it is in the [dirty dozen](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/prog3/ch05_03.htm):

```
/^\*/
```